# Greedy String Tiling in Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am trying to learn greedy string tiling in algorithm

I have two lists as follows:

```
a=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
b=['d','e','a','b','c','f']
```

i would like to retrieve `c=['a','b','c','d','e']`

Another example would be

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1','3']
b = ['3','4','5','2','1','7','8','9','1']
```

`c` should be `['3','4','5','7','8','9','1']`

Right now I am using the following code which works for the latter example but not the former. Can someone help?

```
def gct(a, b):
  if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
    return []
  if a[0] == b[0]:
    return [a[0]] + gct(a[1:], b[1:])
  return max(gct(a, b[1:]), gct(a[1:], b), key=len)
```

I am calling function with

```
gct( ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], ['d','e','a','b','c','f'] )
```

which gives `['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']`, when it should be `['a','b','c','d','e']` or `['d','e','a','b','c']`.

**P.S** The order doesn't matter in the printing of the result. The order is only important while doing the comparisons. The minimum pattern length should be 2

**NOTE** intersect will not solve my problem

Comment: Does the order matter?  Or you just looking for the comment elements in the two lists?

Comment: Does the order of the lists you pass in matter? In the first example you gave, `c` is based on `a` compared with `b`, but in the second example `c` is based on `b` compared with `a`

Comment: Can you show what you mean by it isn't working? Also your `match` function?

Comment: Have you verified that `max()` works the way you expect for letters? Ex: `>>> max('a', 'c')` returns `'c'`

Comment: This seems to me like a question about how to find the intersection of sets in Python. Would `list(set(a).intersect(set(b)))` do what you want?

Comment: It looks like in the first example, you are passing `gct(a,b)` .. but in the second you are passing `gct(b,a)`. That will affect your results

Comment: @Jon but the result is still the same

Comment: @Ekoji will take a look tomorrow. Good luck!

Comment: Your algorithm should get the result as u see. You should restart the search after finding the longest sub-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes can solve the problem. A `minlength` is added to make sure the substr >= `minlength`.

- `maxsub` is used to find the longest substr and return its index in string `a`.
- `markit.a` is used to mark the char position found before in string `a`.
- `while` loop is used to find all the substr (len>=`minlength`)

^

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
a=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
b=['d','e','a','b','c','f']

a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1','3']
b = ['3','4','5','2','1','7','8','9','1']

def gct(a,b,minlength=2):
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return []
    # if py>3.0, nonlocal is better
    class markit:
        a=[0]
        minlen=2
    markit.a=[0]*len(a)
    markit.minlen=minlength

    #output char index
    out=[]

    # To find the max length substr (index)
    # apos is the position of a[0] in origin string
    def maxsub(a,b,apos=0,lennow=0):
        if (len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0):
            return []
        if (a[0]==b[0] and markit.a[apos]!=1 ):
            return [apos]+maxsub(a[1:],b[1:],apos+1,lennow=lennow+1)
        elif (a[0]!=b[0] and lennow>0):
            return []
        return max(maxsub(a, b[1:],apos), maxsub(a[1:], b,apos+1), key=len)
    while True:
        findmax=maxsub(a,b,0,0)
        if (len(findmax)<markit.minlen):
            break
        else:
            for i in findmax:
                markit.a[i]=1
            out+=findmax
    return [ a[i] for i in out]

print gct(a,b)
>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>> ['7', '8', '9', '1', '3', '4', '5']
print gct(a,b,3)
>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
>> ['7', '8', '9', '1', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: This seems correct. I don't know why it was downvoted. You also took note of the minimum length which I forgot. Thank you so much

Comment: Not everyone can understand your question and the algorithm. Some guys  may just think is to get the intersect of two sets (I also understand at start 233)

Comment: The intersect throws an error, let alone solving my problem

Comment: Intersect can't solve the problem when there are repeated chars.