# Greedy String Tiling in Python (string, not character)

Tags: python-3.x, string, pip, greedy

It was the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419576/greedy-string-tiling-in-python) already, but it was answered only to character cases. In small lists that answer works too, but in some real-life texts it stuck with error (to many recursions).
Is there any implementation in form of Python module for Greedy String Tilling algorithm?
What I need is presented in [this](http://pythagoras.pickl.eu/gstform.html) site.
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/apluslms/greedy-string-tiling

Comment: @Camilo Martinez, thanks!

Comment: @Camilo Martinez, is it possible to somehow transform code to search only for words maching, not whole strigs? Or, similar, to search between lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Camilo, I solved my problem modifying solution he found on https://github.com/rvsia/scored-greedy-string-tiling/blob/master/scored_gst/__init__.py.